# NetTrain doesn't accept sparse input?

Tags: machine-learning, sparse-arrays

The following code fails to execute:

```
i = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}];
o = {2, 3, 4};
NetTrain[LinearLayer[], i -> o]
(* NetTrain::invgenout: Output of generator function SparseArray[Automatic,{<<2>>},0,{<<3>>}]->{2,3,4} was incorrect: generator did not return an association or list of rules. *)
```

Applying `Normal` to `i` makes it work.

There is no mention of sparse matrix support in the docs. Is there a way to make `NetTrain` support sparse input, and if not, is it on the product roadmap? MXNet (the backend that Mathematica's deep learning functions internally use) appears to support sparse arrays (see [reference](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/sparse.html)), so hopefully this will eventually be supported.

My use case is a "tall" sparse array with roughly $10^9$ elements, and I'd rather not have it in RAM all at once.

#### Possible workarounds

One way might be to use the `NetTrain[net, f]` method, where `f` grabs a random sample of rows from the sparse matrix, converts the sample into dense form, and feeds them through the net using dense operations. This seems wasteful, though.